# How to find SHORTCODE or SHORTLINK of a media from Instagram API?

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I am going to embed some medias of the logged in user by following Instagram API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/
```

But it needs shortlink or at least shortcode to produce the link. Unfortunately using below API neither returns a shortlink nor shortcode.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSON API response there is a **"link"**, that is the shortlink url:

```
    {
        "data": [{
            "comments": {
                "count": 0
            },
            "caption": {
                "created_time": "1296710352",
                "text": "Inside le truc #foodtruck",
                "from": {
                    "username": "kevin",
                    "full_name": "Kevin Systrom",
                    "type": "user",
                    "id": "3"
                },
                "id": "26621408"
            },
            "likes": {
                "count": 15
            },
            "link": "http://instagr.am/p/BWrVZ/",
            "user": {
                "username": "kevin",
                "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_3_75sq_1295574122.jpg",
                "id": "3"
            },
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but for using embed API it must be considered that the account should not be **private**.

Comment: yes, if you are using API to get shortlink, then you dont have to worry, cause instagram no longer give private profile data via API